# javascript - emebedding mp3

Tags: javascript

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/JavaScript">

// generate random number 1-3

Num = Math.round(Math.random() * 3);
document.write(Num);

//pick song to play based on number generated

if (Num = 1){
        document.getElementById('embMusic').src='iwantyou.mp3';
            }
else
            {
        document.write("you suck");
            }



</script>

<html>

<embed id="embMusic" src="" autostart="true"></embed></html>
```

when i bring this up my browser tells me i have to install plugins?  i know i already have flash or at least WMP... what gives?

Comment: Personally, I use niftyplayer combined with jQuery swfobject which makes things easy: http://www.varal.org/media/niftyplayer/ and http://jquery.thewikies.com/swfobject/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, you can't embed mp3 like that. Use `<audio>` tag instead.

Example:

```
<audio id="embMusic" src="iwantyou.mp3"></audio>
```

And then from javascript:

```
document.getElementById('embMusic').play();
```

Or you can do it without the `<audio>` element, just with javascript, like this:

```
var audio = new Audio();
audio.src = "iwantyou.mp3";
audio.play();
```